# How to get dropzone object elements

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

When using the method "processing"

```
dropzone.on("processing", function(file) {
```

for example, if you console it with

```
console.log(file)
```

you will get

```
File {upload: Object, status: "uploading", previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview.dz-processing, previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview.dz-processing, accepted: true…}
accepted: true
height: 565
lastModified: 1257514480140
lastModifiedDate: Fri Nov 06 2009 08:34:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
name: "smiling picture 7.jpg"
previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-processing.dz-success.dz-complete.dz-image-preview
previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-processing.dz-success.dz-complete.dz-image-preview
processing: true
size: 506340
status: "success"
type: "image/jpeg"
upload: Object
webkitRelativePath: ""
width: 849
xhr: XMLHttpRequest
__proto__: File
```

So you would think you can access any of this with file.*

file.name, file['name'] for example both return "smiling picture 7.jpg" as expected. If you try to get the height or width, they both return "undefined"

So by then doing

```
Object.keys(file).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(key);
});
```

You will get

```
upload
status
previewElement
previewTemplate
accepted
processing
```

So my question is, why is everything so inconsistant. When you log the entire object it shows it all, when you try to access some things they work and some dont and when you cycle the object it only logs certain ones. I need to access the height & width but it appears i can not.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really a proper "answer" but it is a solution for anyone else who needs to access these properties.

Im not sure why some methods access things properly and some do not. If you use

```
dropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
```

instead, the properties work. I would much rather check on the adding or processing method than at the end of the process, but i guess there are limitations to this library.